TypeError: Cannot read property '_resetCount' of undefined
I implemented the basic syc example from the watermelondb docs and ran into this issue I cant find anything about anywhere.
Example snippet
The sync request seems to fail without any push/pull action performed before even any request is made.
It could be my table structure that messes everything up but the documentation is not very helpfull at all.
Example snippet:
import { synchronize } from '@nozbe/watermelondb/sync'

async function mySync() {
  await synchronize({
    database,
    pullChanges: async ({ lastPulledAt, schemaVersion, migration }) => {
      const urlParams = `last_pulled_at=${lastPulledAt}&schema_version=${schemaVersion}&migration=${encodeURIComponent(
        JSON.stringify(migration),
      )}`
      const response = await fetch(`https://my.backend/sync?${urlParams}`)
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(await response.text())
      }

      const { changes, timestamp } = await response.json()
      return { changes, timestamp }
    },
    pushChanges: async ({ changes, lastPulledAt }) => {
      const response = await fetch(`https://my.backend/sync?last_pulled_at=${lastPulledAt}`, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(changes),
      })
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(await response.text())
      }
    },
    migrationsEnabledAtVersion: 1,
  })
}

One of the 4 tables looks like this:
      tableSchema({
        name: 'requests',
        columns: [
          // Fails with and without this column
          { name: '_resetCount', type: 'number' },

          { name: 'created_at', type: 'number' },
          { name: 'updated_at', type: 'number' },
          { name: 'request_id', type: 'number' },
          { name: 'request_created_at', type: 'number', isOptional: false },
          { name: 'sender_auth_id', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'target_auth_id', type: 'string' },
          { name: 'status', type: 'string' },
        ]
      }),

And the coresponding model:
class Request extends Model {
  static table = 'requests';

  
  @readonly @date("created_at") createdAt;
  @readonly @date("updated_at") updatedAt;
// again fails with and without this line
  @field('_resetCount') resetCount;

  @field('request_id') requestId;
  @field('request_created_at') requestCreatedAt;
  @field('sender_auth_id') senderAuthId;
  @field('target_auth_id') targetAuthId;
  @field('status') status;
}

I tried adding/removing columns, resetting the app and database but could not get any further than this issue.
Documentation didn't help at all

Make sure you have set up all imports correctly!
Watermelondb is not yet a finished product and does not warn you if you make any mistakes in that regard.
(solved)
